# ALL Permissions removed from GCP bucket - Bucket is listed but no operation is allowed

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I've create a bucket in GCP to test, I've uploaded a file to test and I've removed all permission of the bucket, including: Editors of project, Owners of project and Viewers.
Now I don't have access to bucket. But It is still listed as a bucket in my "Storage >> Browse", but I can't do anything with it: remove, change permissions, etc.

- When I try to show/detail, an error occurs "Sorry, the server was not able to fulfill your request".
- When I try to delete bucket, an error occours "access denied to bucket".
- When I try to delete bucket using gsedit, an error occours "access denied to bucket".
- When I try to delete whole project, but an error occurs agains.
  Does someone have any idea? How to remove bucket?

Comment: Do you have the role `Owner`? The bucket is owned by the project. The project owner can modify/change IAM access for the bucket.

Comment: Not anymore. Console interface allowed me to remove ALL PERMISSIONS. So my bucket is orphaned. I think Console should not have allowed me to remove everything

Comment: I shared 3 printscreen images in my Google Drive here:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_5PnFW4XXLAHKoR_9Z31sh2P7tlK-IrU?usp=sharing

Comment: You did not answer my question. Are you a Project Owner? The `Owner` role does not need additional permissions to access a bucket owned by the project. Your screenshot indicates you do not have the role `owner`.

Comment: Yes! I've create the project and the bucket. I'm the project owner.

Comment: Go to IAM and list the IAM roles assigned to your identity. Edit your question with these details. You are confusing being the person who created the project versus the role named `owner`.

Comment: I upload a file fig-04 with first print screen of "GPC (menu) :: IAM & Admin >> Roles", and another file RolesForMyProject.csv with all 738 roles from my project. See, I'm ashammed, I know that it is not recommended to remove all permissions of a resource, but GCP could not allow this situation. Is there any SUDO SU? I'm the project owner, bucket is inside my project and I can't do nothing with it.

Comment: SUCCESS !!! Solved. You helped me a LOT. I entered 'GCP (menu) :: IAM & ADMIN' and added again the permission 'Storage Admin' to my own account user. And done! You've alerted me to permissions on IAM!  Thanks a lot.